# Wrong x and y coordinates/pixels of my snake in pygame because of which collision/distance formula is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, pygame

I'm trying to make a fairly simple snake game in Python using PyGame.

I have no idea what's wrong, Somehow the coordinates/pixels are not matching up.

For example let's say my "snake" is at (70, 50) and the "food" is at (372, 216)
The program output by using distance formula is *114.75*, whereas if I calculate it myself it's *344.61*.
So clearly, It's either me wrong, or something's wrong with my code.

Here's my collision function:

```py
def is_collision(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2):
    print(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)
    print(math.pow(x_2 - x_1, 2))
    print(math.pow(y_2 - y_1, 2))
    print(math.sqrt(math.pow(x_2 - x_1, 2) + math.pow(y_2 - y_1, 2)))
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(x_2 - x_1, 2) + math.pow(y_2 - y_1, 2))
    print(distance)
    if distance < 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

these are my variables:

```py
# Player
player_x = 50
player_y = 50
player_width = 20
player_height = 20
player_vel = 20
player_direction = "r"
player_color = (255, 0, 0)

# Food
food_x = random.randint(0, window_size[0])
food_y = random.randint(0, window_size[1])
# food_x = 60
# food_y = 60
# food_eaten = False
food_width = 20
food_height = 20
food_color = (255, 205, 86)
```

and this is my while loop:

```py
while run:
    print(f"Player X = {player_x}")
    print(f"Player Y = {player_y}")
    print(f"Food X = {food_x}")
    print(f"Food Y = {food_y}")
    eat_food = is_collision(player_x, food_x, player_y, food_y)
    # Slows down the loop
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    window.fill(window_bg_color)
    if eat_food:
        food_x = random.randint(0, window_size[0])
        food_y = random.randint(0, window_size[1])

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        run = False

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player_direction != "r":
        player_direction = "l"
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player_direction != "l":
        player_direction = "r"
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player_direction != "d":
        player_direction = "u"
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player_direction != "u":
        player_direction = "d"

    if player_direction == "l":
        player_x -= player_vel
    if player_direction == "r":
        player_x += player_vel
    if player_direction == "u":
        player_y -= player_vel
    if player_direction == "d":
        player_y += player_vel

    if player_x < (0 - player_width):
        player_x = window_size[0] + player_width
    elif player_x > (window_size[0] + player_width):
        player_x = 0 - player_width

    if player_y < (0 - player_height):
        player_y = window_size[1] + player_height
    elif player_y > (window_size[1] + player_height):
        player_y = 0 - player_height

    pygame.draw.rect(window, food_color, (food_x, food_y, food_width, food_height))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, player_color, (player_x, player_y, player_width, player_height))

    pygame.display.update()
```

For clearing purposes, my snake/player moves just fine, nothing is "visually" wrong in it's movement.
The extra print statements are just to check the coordinates for debugging purposes.
I'm getting no error messages by the way.

Comment: found it ! line 5 of your while loop, replace ```...(player_x, food_x, player_y, food_y)``` by ```...(player_x, player_y, food_x, food_y)``` (your did mismatch the coordinates here)

Comment: @gui3 oh, my, God, I can't believe I overlooked such a small thing. I feel so dumb now.

Comment: no need, this happens ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function in a wrong way.

```
eat_food = is_collision(player_x, food_x, player_y, food_y)
```

Since you coded the function like that: `def is_collision(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2):`

you have to call `player_x`, `player_y` and then `food_x` and `food_y`.

It should be: `eat_food = is_collision(player_x, player_y, food_x, food_y)`

Comment: Yes thank you. gui3 pointed that out in the comments. Such a stupid thing to over look, and I had been trying to fix this for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Pointed out by gui3.

I mismatched the coordinates in my function.

Replace this: `eat_food = is_collision(player_x, food_x, player_y, food_y)`

with this: `eat_food = is_collision(player_x, player_y, food_x, food_y)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're inadvertently using two different reference frames.  One where (0,0) is the top-left and the other where (0,0) is the bottom-left.

If we assume that your screen is 500x500 then (372,216) in top-left is also (128,216) in bottom-left coordinates.  The distance from (70,50) to (128,216) is much, much closer to ~114 than ~344.  This of course isn't exact because I don't know exactly how big your screen is.  I might have also messed up if it's (y,x) or (x,y).

I think if you print out your coordinate pairs in the `is_collision` function you'll quickly figure out which is which and solve your problem.